# Want to load images/ video on canvas for my React project, Images are working but not the video

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, react-hooks, html5-canvas

I am trying to upload images/ videos on Canvas. When the user uploads an image, it will display on canvas; if the user uploads a video, it will display on the canvas. I can display the image on Canvas but cannot load the video. Please check the code below and help me to resolve the issue.

```
    import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
    
    const FileUpload = () => {
      const [uploadedFile, setUploadedFile] = useState(null);
      const fileInputRef = useRef(null);
      const canvasRef = useRef(null);
    
      const handleFileChange = (e) => {
        const file = e.target.files[0];
        setUploadedFile(file);
      };    
    
    useEffect(() => {
      if (uploadedFile) {
        const canvas = canvasRef.current;
        const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    
        const mediaElement = document.createElement(
          uploadedFile.type.startsWith('image/') ? 'img' : 'video'
        );
    
        mediaElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(uploadedFile);
    
        mediaElement.onload = () => {
          context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    
          // For videos, play the video and update the canvas during playback
          if (uploadedFile.type.startsWith('video/')) {
            mediaElement.addEventListener('timeupdate', () => {
              context.drawImage(
                mediaElement,
                0,
                0,
                canvas.width,
                canvas.height
              );
            });
    
            mediaElement.play().catch((error) => {
              console.error('Error playing video:', error);
            });
          } else {
            // For images
            context.drawImage(
              mediaElement,
              0,
              0,
              canvas.width,
              canvas.height
            );
          }
        };
      }
    }, [uploadedFile]);
    
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <input type="file" ref={fileInputRef} onChange={handleFileChange} accept="image/*,video/*" />
          
          <canvas ref={canvasRef} width={460} height={300} style={{ marginTop: '20px' }} />
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default FileUpload;
```

Comment: What debugging have you done? Have you verified the `timeupdate` event actually fires?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a vanilla solution that works. It is mostly the same as your solution (with a bunch of helper functions), however it differs in a few things:

1. It appends the created media elements to the DOM
2. It uses the "canplay" event for `<video>`-elements instead of "load"
3. It avoids memory leaks by calling `revokeObjectURL` when a previous media element is removed

```js
const element = {
  app: document.querySelector('#app'),
  file: document.querySelector('#fileSelect'),
  canvas: document.querySelector('#surface'),
  media: null
};



const isImageFile = (file) => file.type.startsWith('image');

const createMediaElement = (file) => {
  return isImageFile(file)
    ? document.createElement('img')
    : document.createElement('video');
};

const render = (elem, context) => {
  const width = context.canvas.width;
  const height = context.canvas.height;
  
  context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  context.drawImage(elem, 0, 0, width, height);
};



const handleFileChange = (event) => {
  const file = event.target.files[0];
  setUploadedFile(file);
};



const runRenderInto = (context) => () => {
  render(element.media, context);
};

const runPlay = (elem) => () => {
  elem.play();
}; 


const setUploadedFile = (file) => {
  if (file) {
    const ctx = element.canvas.getContext('2d');
    const media = createMediaElement(file);
    
    // Removes previously generated media elements
    if (element.media) {
      URL.revokeObjectURL(element.media.src); // <-- Avoid memory leaks!
      element.media.remove();
    }
    
    // Store a reference to the new media element, add some styles to make it dissapear
    element.media = media;
    element.media.style.position = 'fixed';
    element.media.style.bottom = '100%';
    element.media.style.left = '100%';
    
    // Add appropriate event listeners
    if (isImageFile(file)) {
      element.media.addEventListener('load', runRenderInto(ctx));
    } else {
      element.media.addEventListener('timeupdate', runRenderInto(ctx));
      element.media.addEventListener('canplay', runPlay(element.media));
    }
    
    // Add new media element to the DOM.
    // Attach new URL as a last step to ensure the event listeners
    // are properly registered
    element.app.appendChild(element.media);
    element.media.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  }
};



element.file.addEventListener('change', handleFileChange);
```

```html
<div id="app" className="App">
  <input type="file" id="fileSelect" accept="image/*,video/*" />
  <canvas id="surface" width="460" height="300" style="margin-top:20px" />
</div>
```